# Determing the manipulated class by a method invocation of an object of type org.hibernate.Session

Tags: java, hibernate, analysis

I am statically analyzing  an application that uses Hibernate. My aim is to determine the model classes manipulated by each class. Let me give you an example.

```
public class myclass{
  public void saveOrUpdate(Item obj) throws Exception {
    try {
        startOperation();
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        close(session);
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, **myclass** manipulates the class **Item** because there is a method invocation (**session.saveOrUpdate(obj)**) that has as parameter an object of type **Item**. This is a simple example. My problem is how to determine the runtime type of the object passed as a parameter when its static type is **Object**. Here is an example:

```
Public class myclass {
  public void saveOrUpdate(Object obj) throws Exception {
    try {
        startOperation();
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        close(session);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use `getClass()` to get the java.lang.Class object that represents the type of the object. `Class cls = obj.getClass();`  `cls.getName()`

Comment: I think you should assume this class can manipulates all other classes. Or maybe run the application with a 100% test coverage and see what classes passes to this method and mark them as manipulated by this class.

Comment: @Mihir thank you but I can not do that. Since I am analyzing the code statically using JDT all I have are objects of type Expression, SimpleName, etc. Thus, getClass won't be useful.

Comment: @Spara thank you but I am looking for a more precise type determination statically.